# Using emacs for prolog programs

Tags: emacs

Is there any way to tell emacs that it should recognize files which ends with `.pl` as Prolog files?

When I currently load a `.pl` file into emacs it activates the perl-mode. I read some emacs manual pages but I don't really understand what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs comes pre-configured to understabd `.pl` as perl not prolog. To fix that add this to your `.emacs` configuration file founded in your home directory to change the configuration permanently:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(pl\\|pro\\|lgt\\)" . prolog-mode))
```